# If $F(x)=F(y)$ for all the bounded linear functional, then $x=y$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $X$ is a normed linear space. If $F(x)=F(y)$ for all the bounded linear functional $F$ on $X$, then $x=y$.

$0=$$F(x)-F(y)=F(x-y)$ implies $x-y$$\in ker(F)$. But can I say that the intersection of all the kernel$(F)$ is $0$ to conclude $x-y=0$?

Comment: If $x \neq y$ then $z = x-y \neq 0$. Hahn-Banach gives you a linear functional such that $f(z) \neq 0$, i.e. $f(x) \neq f(y)$.

Comment: One might also note from a higher level that this is equivalent to the fact that the weak topology is Hausdorff.

Comment: @JSchlather: Is the weak topology always Hausdorff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Suppose $x\ne y$. If $\{x,y\}$ is linearly independent, define $f:\mathrm{span}\{x,y\}\to \mathbb F$ by $f(ax+by)=a$. Otherwise WLOG assume $x\ne 0$ (as if $x=0$ then $y\ne 0$ and we can switch $x$ and $y$) and define $f:\mathrm{span}\{x\}\to \mathbb F$ by $f(ax)=a$. By Hahn-Banach, we can extend $f$ to a bounded linear functional $F$ on the whole space. Clearly $F(x)\ne F(y)$.